# Accessing swift array inside a swift dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function is that takes a dictionary, and I need to parse the information inside.

I can get an NSArray out of the dictionary, but shouldn't I be able to access a native swift array?

```
class func parseResults(resultsDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Array<Track>? {

        var results : NSArray = resultsDict["results"] as NSArray // This works
        //var results : Array = resultsDict["results"] as Array<AnyObject> // This doesnt work

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` is struct, which is not object so it you can't convert it from `AnyObject`

On the other hand, `NSArray` is class, so you can convert it from `AnyObject`.

Comment: I see, thanks. If I am using NSJSONSerialization class to get an NSArray or NSDictionary should i continue parsing its contents using the foundation classes or their swift native equivalents? In other words, should I just change the resultsDict to be of type NSDictionary?

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization` is Foundation class, I suggest keep use Foundation classes with it to avoid unnecessary bridging. `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` doesn't give you more type-safety anyway.

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect, `NSArray` can be seamlessly bridged to `Array` class. Read my answer and https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_39

Answer (score 1):

A native Swift array is implemented as a struct so it isn't an AnyObject. If you have your dictionary contain `<String, Any>` instead, it should work since Array does conform to Any.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the array in a class and that will solve your problem

```
class WrappedArray<T> {
    var array = Array<T>()
}
var dict = Dictionary<Int, WrappedArray<Int>>()
dict[0] = WrappedArray<Int>()
dict[0].array.append(0)
dict[0].array.append(1)
...
```

You could also implement array methods in the wrapper class and forward them to the array

```
class WrappedArray<T> {
    var array = Array<T>()

    func append(_ newElement:T) {
        self.array.append(newObject)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like a regular array.

`dict[0].append(0)`

instead of

`dict[0].array.append(0)`